# Limit of a function without L'Hopital's rule.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find $$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{3}{x}}\right)$$

This was my quiz question (We can't use L'Hopital's rule as it is not covered yet.)

I know that if we divide a number by a significantly small number we will get a big number. Solving the question from there I got $+ \infty$

Did I do the question correctly? If not, can you show me the right way to do it?

Comment: To say if you did it correctly, we need to see your solution completly.

Comment: Okay, It's a bit difficult for me to write on the computer as there are some ways to write formulas. I'm gonna try

Comment: You could describe what you do, if you are not that familiar with LaTeX.

Comment: Why do you want to argue like "if we divide by a significantly small number... " instead of following systematic procedures to solve such problems? Your method can be compared to the following evaluation of $24^{2}$: since one knows from memory that $25^{2}=625$ the result should be near $625$. The actual answer is significantly less than $625$ and can be obtained via direct multiplication or via $(25-1)^{2}=25^{2}-2\cdot 25+1$.

Answer (score 5):

write $$\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-3x})(1+\sqrt{1+3x})}{x(1+\sqrt{1-3x})}$$ the searched Limit is $$\frac{3}{2}$$
without L'Hospital

Comment: Thanks, I got it

Answer (score 2):

The limit is not $+\infty$, and if it were, then it wouldn't be for the reasons you suggest; more has to be done.

This limit has an indeterminate form, so you're better off doing some algebraic manipulations first. Noting that $x>0$ (since the limit approaches $0$ from above), you can put the expression inside the square root over a common denominator of $x^2$ and pull that out of the root, to obtain
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{1- \sqrt{1-3x}}{x}$$
This still has an indeterminate form, since the top and bottom both tend to $0$ as $x \to 0^+$. But now you can apply l'Hôpital's rule to find the limit.

**Edit:** If you can't use L'Hôpital's rule, then an algebraic solution can be obtained by multiplying the numerator and denominator of the fraction by $1+\sqrt{1-3x}$.

Comment: But...he is not allowed to use L'Hospital.

Comment: @imranfat: The OP edited the question to include that remark *after* I posted my answer... grrr...

Comment: I missed that...

Comment: Using L'H to evaluate this limit is absurd since the limit is already, **by definition**, the value of the derivative at zero of a function that would be involved in L'H. More generally, one should avoid recommending to use L'H to evaluate limits $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$$